# Sending mail via php and from headers?

Tags: php, email

When I send mail from my php script I send it like so

```
$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['username'] . ' - Validate your account at example.com!';
$message = 'http://www.example.com/activate?username=' . $_POST['username'] . '&code=' . $random;
$headers = 'From: noreply@example.com';
```

When the mail comes through to an email the from header shows like this,

**noreply@example.com via web87.extendcp.co.uk**

Is there a way I can stop the via bit from showing?

Comment: When you say "shows like this", you mean in Gmail, don't you?

Comment: yes, I assumed it would be the same for most emails if gmail does it

Answer (score 1):

The only solution would be to use your own SMTP server, or at least another one... If your provider allows that.

It is your provider's web server which modifies the `From:` line here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to implement [DKIM signing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) of your e-mails so Gmail can verify that your server has the right to send e-mail for that domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the IMAP-method from PHP

First connect with the GMail imap-server:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php 
(Make sure you're using SSL/TLS)

Then send the message with imap_mail():
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail.php

```
$host="{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}";
$user=""; // Your GMail-account
$pass=""; // Your GMail-password
if ($mbox=imap_open($host, $user, $pass)) {
    // Connection Success
    $to = "";
    $subject = "";
    $headers = "";
    imap_mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers)
} else {
    // Failed to connect
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

While fge's answer is most likely the correct one here, there's always a chance that your server's mail service won't add it if there's a "friendly" name in the header:

`From: No Reply <noreply@example.com>`

...instead of just:

`From: noreply@example.com`